# Cannot use primitive.ObjectId as a type with the form binding In Gin

Tags: mongodb, go, go-gin

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "net/http"
)

type QueryModel struct {
    Id *primitive.ObjectID `form:"id"`
}

func main() {
    g := gin.Default()

    g.GET("/hello", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var query QueryModel
        if err := c.BindQuery(&query); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, bson.M{"msg": err.Error()})
            return
        }
    })
    g.Run(":9000")
}
```

The result:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9000/hello\?id\=5f2146e27d0e10f02a525412
{"msg":"[\"5f2146e27d0e10f02a525412\"] is not valid value for primitive.ObjectID"}
```

As you can see, that doesn't work in path, query. But it works in body(json)! I don't know how to solve this problem. By the way, I using `string` instead of `primitive.ObejctID` now.

Answer (score 0):

In document in mongo, ObjectId is type of byte array

```
type ObjectID [12]byte
```

Which you can not bind it with a string(query is a string).

So it's a workable way that use string to accept this query and transfom it into [12]byte

Answer (score 0):

To let this get work as GET method

api/v1/order/one?id=62ecc580cc1b1c001a685610

you have to convert string to primitive.ObjectID

```
type OrderQuery struct {
OrdId string `json:"id" form:"id" bson:"id"`}
```

Then, for example, Bind - gin.Context.BindQuery(&ordQuery) as OrderQuery Struct

Then use it like in this example

```
var order Order
docID, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(ordQuery.OrdId)
if err != nil {
    return order, err
}
ordCollection := ...
err = ordCollection.FindOne(ctx, bson.D{{"_id", docID}}).Decode(&order)
if err != nil {
    if err == mongo.ErrNoDocuments {
        return order, err
    }
}
return order, nil
```